# Indesign server data merge

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript, indesign-server

I am trying to do a data merge using Indesign Server.  `test.indd` in the script below already has all the merge fields assigned. I only need this script to open the file, do the merge, and save the merged file. The file that gets saved is the original `test.indd` file, and not the merged file. I'm not sure how to access the merged file.

```
var myDocument = app.open(File("/C/inetpub/wwwroot/datamerge/test.indd"));

with (app.dataMergeOptions) { 
 linkImages = true; 
 removeBlankLines = false; 
 createNewDocument = true; 
 documentSize = 100; 
} // (end of dataMergeOptions) 

myDocument.dataMergeProperties.mergeRecords();
myDocument.save(new File("/C/inetpub/wwwroot/datamerge/mergedOutput.indd"));
myDocument.close ();
```

If someone can have a look and let me know what I'm missing. Or direct me in the direction I should be going.

Answer (score 1):

Your dataMergeOptions tell the application to create a new document but you are saving the document in your myDocument variable which is your template.  You need to either get a hold of the newly created document and save that or remove the createNewDocument option.

Comment: Hi @Anna how can i get hold of newly created document (after merging)?

Comment: try using 'app.activeDocument.save' instead of 'myDocument.save' - I haven't played with the merge function much but it would make sense that your newly merged document would become the active one post merge.